# Compare 2 table columns and update new column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like this:

[image]

[image]

For example in first row from table 2 col value is 3661 and its equal to 'med' from table 1 I want to update class from table 1 with 'MED' and ...

This is the code I wrote but something is wrong :(

```
UPDATE table1 SET
class = ( CASE 
            WHEN table2.col = table1.med
            THEN  'MED'
            --------------------------------
            WHEN table2.col = table1.mgl
            THEN  'MGL'
            --------------------------------
            WHEN table2.col = table1.rhp
            THEN  'RHP'
            --------------------------------
            WHEN table2.col = table1.epd
            THEN  'EPD'
            --------------------------------
            WHEN table2.col = table1.jpa
            THEN  'JPA'
            --------------------------------
            ELSE  'NULL'
          FROM 
            table1 LEFT outer JOIN table2
            )
```

Comment: add join condition:from table1 left outer join table2 **ON table1.number=table2.number**

Comment: You missed the `END` for the `CASE`

Comment: i added join condition:  ON table1.number=table2.number and END but didnt worked

Comment: is number in table2 a primary key?

Comment: which rdbms , is it mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code. you did not mention which database you use,
Anyway try this:

```
   UPDATE table1 
    SET class = ( CASE 
                WHEN table2.col = table1.med
                THEN  'MED'
                --------------------------------
                WHEN table2.col = table1.mgl
                THEN  'MGL'
                --------------------------------
                WHEN table2.col = table1.rhp
                THEN  'RHP'
                --------------------------------
                WHEN table2.col = table1.epd
                THEN  'EPD'
                --------------------------------
                WHEN table2.col = table1.jpa
                THEN  'JPA'
                --------------------------------
                ELSE  'NULL'
    END)
    from table1 left join table2 on table1.number=table2.number
```

Comment: thanks it worked! my mistake was that i put 'END' after 'From'

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET class = COALESCE((SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN table2.col = table1.med THEN 'MED'
                                          WHEN table2.col = table1.mgl THEN 'MGL'
                                          . . .
                                     END) as newval
                          FROM table2
                         ), 'NULL')
```

This is a bit tricky.  You need to decide which row you want if there are multiple matches.  The above chooses an arbitrary value among the matches.

The `coalesce()` is to handle the case where there are no matches.  The subquery will return `NULL` in that case.

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.  Specific databases might have other ways of writing this query.

Comment: im getting this error-->  Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Comment: @meysammotamedi . . . The query in this answer has only one column in the subquery.  It cannot be generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it in MySQL, this is working

```
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.number = T2.number
set T1.class = 
( CASE 
  WHEN T2.col = T1.med
  THEN  'MED'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.mgl
  THEN  'MGL'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.rhp
  THEN  'RHP'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.epd
  THEN  'EPD'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.jpa
  THEN  'JPA'
  ELSE  'NULL' 
  END
  )
```

EDIT:
  In case of MS SQL SERVER,  you can use this

```
UPDATE Table1 
set class = 
( CASE 
  WHEN T2.col = T1.med
  THEN  'MED'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.mgl
  THEN  'MGL'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.rhp
  THEN  'RHP'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.epd
  THEN  'EPD'
  WHEN T2.col = T1.jpa
  THEN  'JPA'
  ELSE  'NULL' 
  END
  )
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.number = T2.number
```